# jQuery: send keystroke

Tags: jquery, send, keystroke

i'm having a widget with a search-textbox. when pressing enter in it, search starts.

i now want to trigger that enter key by code. in other words, i want to send the enter-keystroke to the textbox.

how does it work?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise that you trigger the search rather than triggering the keystroke.
Obviously, that can be done just by calling the client-side search code or, if searching takes place server-side, submitting the form with the correct arguments/values.

Answer (score 2):

Set the onKeyUp event for the input. Get the event key code and if the keycode is enter, then append it to your box. Would look *something* like this:

```
function checkEnter(e) {
     if (checkKey(e) == 13) {
          $("#something").append('13');
     }
}

function checkKey(e) {
    var keynum;
    var keychar;
    var numcheck;

    if (e.keyCode) {
        keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if (e.which) {
        keynum = e.which;
    }
    return keynum;
}
...


<input type="textbox" id="something" onkeyup="checkEnter(event)">
```